# How to wrap text of HTML button with fixed width?

Tags: html, css, button, word-wrap

I just noticed that if you give an HTML button a fixed width, the text inside the button is never wrapped. I've tried it with word-wrap, but that cuts of the word even though there are spaces available to wrap on.

How can I make the text of an HTML button with a fixed width wrap like any tablecell would?

```html
<td class="category_column">
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DataList1$ctl12$ProCat_NameButton" value="Roos Sturingen / Sensors" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl12_ProCat_NameButton" class="outset" style="height:118px;width:200px;font-size:18px;color:#7F7F7F;width:200px;white-space:pre;"
  />
</td>
```

The CSS classes do nothing but adding borders and modify the padding.
If I add `word-wrap:break-word` to this button, it will wrap it like this:

```
Roos Sturingen / Sen
sors
```

And I don't want it to cut of in the middle of a word if it is possible to cut it off between words.

Answer (score 682, accepted):

I found that you can make use of the white-space CSS property:

```css
white-space: normal;
```

And it will break the words as normal text.

Comment: @MGOwen it's ok now - we deadened IE6 in the meantime.

Comment: The other answers suggesting `word-wrap: break-word;` didn't work for me, but this did.

Answer (score 36):

```
white-space: normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Mine works with both

Answer (score 8):

You can force it (browser permitting, I imagine) by inserting line breaks in the HTML source, like this:

```
<INPUT value="Line 1
Line 2">
```

Of course working out where to place the line breaks is not necessarily trivial...

If you can use an HTML `<BUTTON>` instead of an `<INPUT>`, such that the button label is the element's content rather than its `value` attribute, placing that content inside a `<SPAN>` with a `width` attribute that is a few pixels narrower than that of the button seems to do the trick (even in IE6 :-).

Comment: For something very simple you can also use <button> with a <br> at the desired break point.

Comment: Used to work, but no longer works in recent versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

```
   white-space: normal;
   word-wrap: break-word;
```

"Both" worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I have found that a button works, but that you'll want to add `style="height: 100%;"` to the button so that it will show more than the first line on Safari for iPhone iOS 5.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Multi-line buttons like that are not really trivial to implement. [This page](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/imagebutton.html) has an interesting (though somewhat dated) discussion on the subject. Your best bet would probably be to either drop the multi-line requirement or to create a custom button using e.g. `div`s and CSS, and adding some JavaScript to make it work as a button.

Comment: The problem is that I am using ASP.Net, using the asp:button control with CommandName and CommandArgument attributes. I can't just use an other control.

Answer (score 2):

If we have some inner divisions inside `<button>` tag like this-

```
<button class="top-container">
    <div class="classA">
       <div class="classB">
           puts " some text to get print." 
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="class1">
       <div class="class2">
           puts " some text to get print." 
       </div>
     </div>
</button>
```

Sometime Text of class A get overlap on class1 data because these both are in a single button tag.
I try to break the tex using-

```
 word-wrap: break-word;         /* All browsers since IE 5.5+ */
 overflow-wrap: break-word;     /* Renamed property in CSS3 draft spec */
```

But this won't worked then I try this-

```
white-space: normal;
```

after removing above css properties and got my task done.

Hope will work for all !!!

Comment: How does this differs from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1194680/2441442) answer?

Comment: It is, if you notice, I have used that with button tag.

Comment: Divs are not allowed within a button, it is not correct HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
line-break: anywhere;
```

or

```
word-break: break-all;
```

also possible.