# Button text wrap: vertical alignment issue

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, word-wrap

I needed to wrap text inside my buttons so I found this solution:

[How to wrap text of html button with fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862010/how-to-wrap-text-of-html-button-with-fixed-width)

However, after applying the solution I noticed that the vertical alignment of buttons changes. Here is the screenshot:

[image: http://tinyurl.com/88hah7l]

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Wrap</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        INPUT.StandardButton
        {           
            WIDTH: 87px; 
            HEIGHT: 38px;
            font-size: 10pt; 
            Font-weight: bold;                      
            cursor: pointer;
            FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Verdana;
            COLOR: #0049A5;                                 
        }

    </style>

<head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="NoWrap" class="StandardButton" />
    <input type="button" value="This is Test 1" class="StandardButton" style="white-space: normal;" />
    <input type="button" value="This is Test 2" class="StandardButton" style="white-space: normal;"  />
    <input type="button" value="This is Test 3" class="StandardButton" style="white-space: normal;" />

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what is causing the alignment change? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what's causing this misalignment, but apparently `vertical-align:middle` seems to fix it:

http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/Dr5hM/

Comment: In chrome the white space property on buttons are set to pre so the boxes with it set to normal that wrap seem to be the only ones that show this problem. Thats very odd.

Comment: Vertical alignment indeed fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for updating so fast but I just noticed that adding vertical-align:middle will remove text wrapping in IE9. Works fine in Chrome however. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, compared the differences in JSFiddle and my html and found out that DOCTYPE needs to be set to <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I had the same problem even with <!DOCTYPE html> but `vertical-align` solved it for me nonetheless. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing it either but valign, putting the buttons in a table, our making the buttons width shorter should clear this up very quickly.