# Can I set word-wrap:break-word to input of type submit?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, html-input

Can the CSS `word-wrap: break-word` be applied to an `<input/>` of type `submit`?

Ive applied that css but its not doing anything which isnt what i expected. Im trying to make my submit input wrap around a heading that comes before it.

For [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RNZE/), can the input or link wrap the heading? So I want the first word of the button and link to be on the same line as the heading and the next word to drop down to the next line.

```
<div class="cont">

    <div>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <input type="submit" id="edit-remove" value="remove room" class="form-submit">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <a href="#">remove room</a>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

h3 {
    float: left;
}

a, input {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.cont {
    background: grey;
    width: 141px;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Uhm. Code sample, please? I don't understand what you have to work with... you are using a `<input type="submit"/>` that you want to be on the next line after a header element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible for the `value` attribute on `<input type="submit"/>`, because not only the text but the whole button would need to break the line. Cannot imagine how this should work. (Of course, inside the button you can have line breaks: [How to wrap text of html button with fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862010/how-to-wrap-text-of-html-button-with-fixed-width)).

But you can do this on `<a/>` by displaying both the headline and the anchor `inline` without floating them:

```
h3, a {
    display: inline;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9RNZE/2/).